AWS Persistent Storage failed to refresh cached credentials
I'm trying to create a test pod which has a persistent volume.
This is my pod.yaml and pvc.yaml on an an EKS cluster.
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-pvc
  namespace: my-ns  
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce  
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi 
  storageClassName: gp2  


apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
  namespace: my-ns
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: busybox  
      command: ["sleep", "3600"]  
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /mnt/data  
          name: my-pvc-volume 
  volumes:
    - name: my-pvc-volume  
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: my-pvc  

If I describe the PVC, it shows as follows:

Warning ProvisioningFailed 4m58s (x5 over 14m)
ebs.csi.aws.com_ebs-csi-controller-dd646df8-7ddpr_aca98eff-9b9a-4bce-8049-b34905dffc7e
failed to provision volume with StorageClass "gp2": rpc error: code =
Internal desc = Could not create volume "pvc-1bed8d46-f728-4b15-b7e │
f-9a5425c0814d": could not create volume in EC2: operation error
EC2: CreateVolume, get identity: get credentials: failed to refresh
cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds:
GetMetadata, request canceled, context deadline exceeded
Normal ExternalProvisioning 71s (x99 over 25m)
persistentvolume-controller Waiting for a volume to be created either
by the external provisioner 'ebs.csi.aws.com' or manually by the
system administrator. If volume creation is delayed, please
verify that the provisioner is running and correctly registered.

The logs of EBS-CSI pod in kube-system shows the error: "failed to refresh cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found"

E1005 20:52:29.823331 1 driver.go:108] "GRPC error" err="rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not create volume "pvc-1bed8d46-f728-4b15-b7ef-9a5425c0814d": could not create volume in EC2: operation error EC2: CreateVolume, get identity: get credentials: failed to refresh cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, canceled, context deadline exceeded"


You may create a Role with AmazonEBSCSIDriverPolicy attached. Then update addon Amazon EBS CSI Driver to set "IAM role for service account (IRSA)".
